# Bad understanding in negative look around

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to improve a regular expression.

I have this string:

```
String myString = 
    "stuffIDontWant$KEYWORD$stuffIWant$stuffIWant$KEYWORD$stuffIDontWant";
```

And I made this to substract only the stuff I want:

```
    String regex = "\\$KEYWORD\\$.+\\$.+\\$KEYWORD\\$";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);

    if(m.find()){
        String result = stuff.substring(m.start(), m.end());
    }
```

The goal is to get `stuffIWant$stuffIWant` and then split it with the character `$`, so, looking to improve it and avoid to import Patter and Matcher to my java source, I read about lookarounds, so my second approach is:

```
//Deletes what matches regex
    myString.replaceAll(regex, ""); 
// Does nothing, and i thought it was just the opposite of the above instruction.
    myString.replaceAll("(?! "+regex+")", "");
```

What is the correct way and where is my concept wrong?

Comment: I think you misunderstood what lookaround does. Lookaround matches a position in text (like a blinking cursor) and not actual characters. Because you replace it with nothing, no actual characters are replaced.

Comment: @Arjen Thanks, I will then read more about it (just dont have the time right now), however, do you have a better solution for what i did that works using pattern and matcher?

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution? Seems good enough to me! Like acheong87 suggests, you can use captures to avoid having to split the string you find.

Comment: @Arjen I just thought I could do it with a single instruction.

Comment: You can, but as a result your regular expression will be more complex. Dealing with regular expressions is usually hard enough already. I think you're better off with the way you handle things right now. It's more maintainable in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting there!  But most would use *capture groups*.

```
\\$KEYWORD\\$(.+)\\$(.+)\\$KEYWORD\\$
             ^  ^   ^  ^
```

These parentheses will store what they enclose, i.e. *capture*.  The first set will be indexed 1, the second set will be indexed 2.  You can try this with the above expression to see what's happening.

```
if (m.find()) {
    int count = m.groupCount();
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        System.out.println(m.group(i));
    }
}
```

It is possible to solve with lookarounds too, but unnecessary:

```
(?<=\\$KEYWORD\\$).+?\\$.+?(?=\\$KEYWORD\\$)
^^^^             ^  ^     ^^^^             ^
```

Comment: Also, I would replace ``(.+)`` with ``(.+?)`` to invoke _non-greedy matching_.  You needn't worry about that at this level, though.